# accord.net Neldermead optimization avoid initial trap in c#

Tags: c#, accord.net

I'm trying to use the NelderMead solver provided by accord.net for an optimization as follows:

```
var solution = new NelderMead(vecCMrIni.Length, CMOpt);
// CMOpt is the function to be minimized    
for (int m = 0; m < vecCMrIni.Length; m++) // set lower and upper bound
        {   solution.LowerBounds[m] = vecCMrLB[m];
            solution.UpperBounds[m] = vecCMrUB[m];}
 bool success = solution.Minimize(vecCMrIni);// minimize CMOpt, with vecCMrIni as initial.
```

Unfortunately, it turns out the solver would produce a solution that exactly the same as the initial vector vecCMrIni. Is there any way to overcome this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and in my case, it was solved setting the value of "Maximum Value":

```
// (this value depends on your function, but try to put a huge negative value)
solution.MaximumValue = -1e6;
```

Before this change, the "Minimize" method was returning with status: `MinimumAllowedValueReached`